# Firebase Sorting is not working properly in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a course app in flutter. so there is a subcollection for displaying episodes inside the course. and I'm sending episode numbers when creating the episodes to sort the episode with the value using the firebase `orderBy` function.
it's working but not ordering properly. (what I mean by working is it's sorting differently but messed up).

here are all codes and details

### **Read Episode code**

```
  @override
  Stream<List<EpisodesModel>> readEpisode({
    required id,
  }) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('courses')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('eps')
        .orderBy('episodeNum', descending: false) // the eps num is the number that I send to firebase db when creating course 
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((doc) => EpisodesModel.fromJson(doc.data()))
            .toList());
  }
```

**but this is how the value is sorting**

[image]

please comment if any other code is needed,

Comment: Why you use after snapshoot a map ? Instead of `.listen()` ?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your db? Is it possible you are storing episodeNum as a String instead of a number?

Comment: @h8moss im storing as String

Comment: @Mises to map the value to list

Comment: @mishalhaneef ok, so, don't do that... a string is sorted alphabetically instead of by increase, if it's a number store it as a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the values in your `episodeNum` field are stored as string values, and not as numbers. And in the [lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) (which Firestore uses for string values) "10" comes before "2", just as "aa" comes before "b".

To fix the problem, store the `episodeNum` values as numbers in the database, and Firestore will order them correctly.